Why am I getting a 429 - resource exhausted despite being under my limit on the Gemini AI studio API despite using Pay as you Go?
I continually get the following error code when trying to access the Gemini API (specifically 1.5-pro):
{
  "error": {
    "code": 429,
    "message": "Resource has been exhausted (e.g. check quota).",
    "status": "RESOURCE_EXHAUSTED"
  }
}

I am using the aistudio API (aistudio.google.com). The keys are listed as paid (weirdly enough this is on a per-project basis, even though they're all connected to the same account).
What's also frustrating is that there is no way to see how many RPD I've actually used in the console. I can see my RPM but not per day.
Anyone have any idea why this is? Should I be using Vertex instead?
EDIT: Code is just your standard Curl request call from gemini website:
curl \
  -H 'Content-Type: application/json' \
  -d '{"contents":[{"parts":[{"text":"Explain how AI works"}]}]}' \
  -X POST 'https://generativelanguage.googleapis.com/v1beta/models/gemini-1.5-pro-latest:generateContent?key=<Redacted>'


please edit your question and include your code.

Based on statement here (https://ai.google.dev/pricing), it states: **Specified rate limits are not guaranteed and actual capacity may vary.  Apply for an increased maximum rate limit (for paid tier only).. Apply link (https://ai.google.dev/gemini-api/docs/quota)

You are using an API Key. How do you know API requests are paid rather than free? Do you have a Google Workspace account? We need more context to help you. The Gemini API that you are using is a simplified version. The Vertex API offers more features and control.

I know the API requests are paid and not free because in the AI Studio it says the key is "paid". It is a google workspace.

I had the same 429 error... I had to connect a GCP Billing Account to my Google Workspace org. As soon as I did that, the error resolved...very confusing.

As described on this forum, it can be a rate limit error.
